# Crash when compiling basic code with emcc -O2

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors, release, emscripten

I am trying to compile some basic test code with emcc -O2, and for a reason that I do not understand, the compilation fails at some point:

```
D:\Projects\jsport>call emcc "../src/lib.cpp" -o emscripten_test-min.js -O2 -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_testFct']" -s RESERVED_FUNCTION_POINTERS=1
WARNING:root:generating system asset: optimizer.exe...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\\emcc", line 1602, in <module>
    flush_js_optimizer_queue()
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\\emcc", line 1505, in flush_js_optimizer_queue
    run_passes(chunks[0], title, just_split=False, just_concat=False)
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\\emcc", line 1478, in run_passes
    final = shared.Building.js_optimizer(final, passes, debug_level >= 4, js_optimizer_extra_info, just_split=just_split, just_concat=just_concat)
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\tools\shared.py", line 1634, in js_optimizer
    ret = js_optimizer.run(filename, passes, NODE_JS, debug, extra_info, just_split, just_concat)
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\tools\js_optimizer.py", line 538, in run
    return temp_files.run_and_clean(lambda: run_on_js(filename, passes, js_engine, source_map, extra_info, just_split, just_concat))
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\tools\tempfiles.py", line 64, in run_and_clean
    return func()
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\tools\js_optimizer.py", line 538, in <lambda>
    return temp_files.run_and_clean(lambda: run_on_js(filename, passes, js_engine, source_map, extra_info, just_split, just_concat))
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\tools\js_optimizer.py", line 428, in run_on_js
    if not use_native(passes, source_map) or not get_native_optimizer():
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\tools\js_optimizer.py", line 182, in get_native_optimizer
    return get_optimizer('optimizer.exe', [], ignore_build_errors)
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\tools\js_optimizer.py", line 166, in get_optimizer
    return shared.Cache.get(name, create_optimizer_cmake, extension='exe')
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\tools\cache.py", line 41, in get
    temp = creator()
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\tools\js_optimizer.py", line 117, in create_optimizer_cmake
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['cmake', '-G', cmake_generator, '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE='+cmake_build_type, shared.path_from_root('tools', 'optimizer')], cwd=build_path, stdin=log_output, stdout=log_output, stderr=log_output)
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\python\2.7.5.3_64bit\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\python\2.7.5.3_64bit\lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
```

If I remove the O2 option, the exact same code compiles fine and can be called from Javascript.

Any idea how to fix this ?

---

The code I am trying to compile:

**Lib.h:**

```
#ifndef LIB_H
#define LIB_H

extern "C" {

typedef void (*invoke_oncomplete_callback_t)(int, const char*, const char*);

void testFct(const void *arr_data_rgba, int arr_width, int arr_height, int job_id, invoke_oncomplete_callback_t callback);

}

#endif //LIB_H
```

**Lib.cpp:**

```
#include <sstream>
#include "lib.h"

// Internal C++ library functions 
namespace impl {

void testFct(const void *arr_data, int arr_width, int arr_height, int job_id, invoke_oncomplete_callback_t callback)
{
    // Call the callback with the result
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Inversion done in " << 0 << "s";
    callback(job_id, "", ss.str().c_str());
}

}   // namespace impl

// Exposed C library function 
void testFct(const void *arr_data, int arr_width, int arr_height, int job_id, invoke_oncomplete_callback_t callback)
{
    impl::testFct(arr_data, arr_width, arr_height, job_id, callback);
}
```

---

The output with EMCC_DEBUG=1:

```
D:\Projects\jsport>set EMCC_DEBUG=1
D:\Projects\jsport>call emcc "../src/lib.cpp" -o emscripten_test-min.js -O2 -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_testFct']" -s RESERVED_FUNCTION_POINTERS=1
DEBUG:root:PYTHON not defined in C:\Users\MyUserName/.emscripten, using "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\python\2.7.5.3_64bit\python.exe"
WARNING:root:invocation: D:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\\emcc ../src/lib.cpp -o emscripten_test-min.js -O2 -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=['_testFct'] -s RESERVED_FUNCTION_POINTERS=1  (in D:\Projects\jsport)
INFO:root:(Emscripten: Running sanity checks)
DEBUG:root:compiling to bitcode
DEBUG:root:emcc step "parse arguments and setup" took 0.00 seconds
DEBUG:root:compiling source file: ../src/lib.cpp
DEBUG:root:running: D:\Program Files\Emscripten\clang\e1.35.0_64bit\clang++ -target asmjs-unknown-emscripten -D__EMSCRIPTEN_major__=1 -D__EMSCRIPTEN_minor__=35 -D__EMSCRIPTEN_tiny__=0 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -nostdinc -Xclang -nobuiltininc -Xclang -nostdsysteminc -Xclang -isystemD:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\system\local\include -Xclang -isystemD:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\system\include\compat -Xclang -isystemD:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\system\include -Xclang -isystemD:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\system\include\emscripten -Xclang -isystemD:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\system\include\libc -Xclang -isystemD:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\system\lib\libc\musl\arch\emscripten -Xclang -isystemD:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\system\include\libcxx -O2 -mllvm -disable-llvm-optzns -std=c++03 ../src/lib.cpp -Xclang -isystemD:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\system\include\SDL -emit-llvm -c -o C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppmxhg5\lib_0.o
DEBUG:root:emcc step "bitcodeize inputs" took 0.61 seconds
DEBUG:root:optimizing ../src/lib.cpp
DEBUG:root:emcc: LLVM opts: -O3 -disable-loop-vectorization -disable-slp-vectorization -vectorize-loops=false -vectorize-slp=false -vectorize-slp-aggressive=false  [num inputs: 1]
DEBUG:root:emcc step "process inputs" took 0.12 seconds
DEBUG:root:will generate JavaScript
DEBUG:root:including libcxx_noexcept.a
DEBUG:root:including libcxxabi.bc
DEBUG:root:including libc.bc
DEBUG:root:including dlmalloc.bc
DEBUG:root:emcc step "calculate system libraries" took 0.05 seconds
DEBUG:root:linking: ['C:\\Users\\MyUserName\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmppmxhg5\\lib_0_1.o', 'C:\\Users\\MyUserName\\.emscripten_cache\\libcxxabi.bc', 'C:\\Users\\MyUserName\\.emscripten_cache\\libc.bc', 'C:\\Users\\MyUserName\\.emscripten_cache\\dlmalloc.bc', 'C:\\Users\\MyUserName\\.emscripten_cache\\libcxx_noexcept.a']
DEBUG:root:adding object C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppmxhg5\lib_0_1.o to link
DEBUG:root:adding object C:\Users\MyUserName\.emscripten_cache\libcxxabi.bc to link
DEBUG:root:adding object C:\Users\MyUserName\.emscripten_cache\libc.bc to link
DEBUG:root:adding object C:\Users\MyUserName\.emscripten_cache\dlmalloc.bc to link
DEBUG:root:considering archive C:\Users\MyUserName\.emscripten_cache\libcxx_noexcept.a
DEBUG:root:adding object C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp\tmprfwi8k\string_fb1646b4.cpp.o to link
DEBUG:root:adding object C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp\tmprfwi8k\ios_1da97a69.cpp.o to link
DEBUG:root:adding object C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp\tmprfwi8k\locale_528bea5a.cpp.o to link
DEBUG:root:adding object C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp\tmprfwi8k\memory_8c4a4594.cpp.o to link
DEBUG:root:adding object C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp\tmprfwi8k\system_error_7d190770.cpp.o to link
DEBUG:root:adding object C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp\tmprfwi8k\mutex_50c49967.cpp.o to link
DEBUG:root:adding object C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp\tmprfwi8k\condition_variable_1b9bbc16.cpp.o to link
DEBUG:root:adding object C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp\tmprfwi8k\stdexcept_e242ef16.cpp.o to link
DEBUG:root:adding object C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp\tmprfwi8k\thread_b13652bb.cpp.o to link
DEBUG:root:adding object C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp\tmprfwi8k\future_fce87bc4.cpp.o to link
DEBUG:root:adding object C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp\tmprfwi8k\exception_f3e64688.cpp.o to link
DEBUG:root:done running loop of archive C:\Users\MyUserName\.emscripten_cache\libcxx_noexcept.a
DEBUG:root:emcc step "link" took 0.81 seconds
DEBUG:root:saving intermediate processing steps to C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp
DEBUG:root:(not saving intermediate C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp\emcc-0-basebc.bc because deferring linking)
DEBUG:root:emcc: LLVM opts: -strip-debug -disable-verify -internalize -internalize-public-api-list=testFct,malloc,free,__errno_location,fflush,__cxa_can_catch,__cxa_is_pointer_type -globaldce -pnacl-abi-simplify-preopt -pnacl-abi-simplify-postopt -disable-loop-vectorization -disable-slp-vectorization -vectorize-loops=false -vectorize-slp=false -vectorize-slp-aggressive=false  [num inputs: 15]
DEBUG:root:emcc step "post-link" took 0.37 seconds
DEBUG:root:LLVM => JS
DEBUG:root:emscript: llvm backend: D:\Program Files\Emscripten\clang\e1.35.0_64bit\llc C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppmxhg5\emscripten_test-min.bc -march=js -filetype=asm -o C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp\tmp1zqxhc.4.js -emscripten-reserved-function-pointers=1 -O2
DEBUG:root:  emscript: llvm backend took 0.236999988556 seconds
DEBUG:root:emscript: js compiler glue
DEBUG:root:  emscript: glue took 0.319000005722 seconds
DEBUG:root:asm text sizes[[1463028, 17491], 5292, 200, 3702, 0, 5207, 23191, 1086, 268, 2736, 2080]
DEBUG:root:  emscript: final python processing took 0.00999999046326 seconds
DEBUG:root:emcc step "emscript (llvm=>js)" took 0.60 seconds
DEBUG:root:wrote memory initialization to emscripten_test-min.js.mem
DEBUG:root:emcc step "source transforms" took 0.05 seconds
DEBUG:root:running js post-opts
DEBUG:root:applying js optimization passes: asm eliminate simplifyExpressions simplifyIfs registerize minifyNames asmLastOpts last minifyWhitespace cleanup
chunkification: num funcs: 707 actual num chunks: 3 chunk size range: 522935 - 450885
WARNING:root:generating system asset: optimizer.exe...
DEBUG:root:building native optimizer via CMake: optimizer.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\\emcc", line 1602, in <module>
    flush_js_optimizer_queue()
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\\emcc", line 1505, in flush_js_optimizer_queue
    run_passes(chunks[0], title, just_split=False, just_concat=False)
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\\emcc", line 1478, in run_passes
    final = shared.Building.js_optimizer(final, passes, debug_level >= 4, js_optimizer_extra_info, just_split=just_split, just_concat=just_concat)
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\tools\shared.py", line 1634, in js_optimizer
    ret = js_optimizer.run(filename, passes, NODE_JS, debug, extra_info, just_split, just_concat)
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\tools\js_optimizer.py", line 538, in run
    return temp_files.run_and_clean(lambda: run_on_js(filename, passes, js_engine, source_map, extra_info, just_split, just_concat))
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\tools\tempfiles.py", line 64, in run_and_clean
    return func()
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\tools\js_optimizer.py", line 538, in <lambda>
    return temp_files.run_and_clean(lambda: run_on_js(filename, passes, js_engine, source_map, extra_info, just_split, just_concat))
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\tools\js_optimizer.py", line 428, in run_on_js
    if not use_native(passes, source_map) or not get_native_optimizer():
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\tools\js_optimizer.py", line 182, in get_native_optimizer
    return get_optimizer('optimizer.exe', [], ignore_build_errors)
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\tools\js_optimizer.py", line 166, in get_optimizer
    return shared.Cache.get(name, create_optimizer_cmake, extension='exe')
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\tools\cache.py", line 41, in get
    temp = creator()
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0\tools\js_optimizer.py", line 117, in create_optimizer_cmake
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['cmake', '-G', cmake_generator, '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE='+cmake_build_type, shared.path_from_root('tools', 'optimizer')], cwd=build_path, stdin=log_output, stdout=log_output, stderr=log_output)
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\python\2.7.5.3_64bit\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "D:\Program Files\Emscripten\python\2.7.5.3_64bit\lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/emscripten-discuss/xtxwXwVqVXg/IL3LT45JBAAJ), the crash seems to be due to a problem when searching for a local compiler.

Setting the environnement variable EMCC_NATIVE_OPTIMIZER = 0 fixes the problem, with the downside of slowing the compilation down.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the js_optimizer.py [(emsdk\fastcomp\emscripten\tools\js_optimizer.py line 108)](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emsdk) file I noticed that it doesn't support the Visual Studio 2019 CMake Generator.
Changing the code from

```
  if WINDOWS:
    # Poor man's check for whether or not we should attempt 64 bit build
    if os.environ.get('ProgramFiles(x86)'):
      cmake_generators = [
        'Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64',
        'Visual Studio 15 2017',
        'Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64',
        'Visual Studio 14 2015',
        'Visual Studio 12 Win64', # The year component is omitted for compatibility with older CMake.
        'Visual Studio 12',
        'Visual Studio 11 Win64',
        'Visual Studio 11',
        'MinGW Makefiles',
        'Unix Makefiles',
      ]
    else:
      cmake_generators = [
        'Visual Studio 15 2017',
        'Visual Studio 14 2015',
        'Visual Studio 12',
        'Visual Studio 11',
        'MinGW Makefiles',
        'Unix Makefiles',
      ]
  else:
    cmake_generators = ['Unix Makefiles']
```

To:

```
      if WINDOWS:
    # Poor man's check for whether or not we should attempt 64 bit build
    if os.environ.get('ProgramFiles(x86)'):
      cmake_generators = [
        "Visual Studio 16 2019 Win64",
        "Visual Studio 16 2019",
        'Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64',
        'Visual Studio 15 2017',
        'Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64',
        'Visual Studio 14 2015',
        'Visual Studio 12 Win64', # The year component is omitted for compatibility with older CMake.
        'Visual Studio 12',
        'Visual Studio 11 Win64',
        'Visual Studio 11',
        'MinGW Makefiles',
        'Unix Makefiles',
      ]
    else:
      cmake_generators = [
        "Visual Studio 16 2019",
        'Visual Studio 15 2017',
        'Visual Studio 14 2015',
        'Visual Studio 12',
        'Visual Studio 11',
        'MinGW Makefiles',
        'Unix Makefiles',
      ]
  else:
    cmake_generators = ['Unix Makefiles']
```

Solved this issue for me.

The below links for some extra info:

For a list of Visual Studio supported [cmake generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/customize-cmake-settings?view=vs-2019#advanced-settings)